# Issues with MantisBT and PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, mantis, phpstorm-2018.1

I happily used PhpStorm and MantisBT together for months, but now I'm facing a strange problem.

Trying to establish a connection to my mantis instance (self hosted), I get the error:

> Request failed. Reason: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

While I understand, what this error message means, I can't tell why it happens and I can't control the response I get from Mantis.

I neither found answers at the PhpStorm docs nor at Google nor at the Mantis bug tracker itself.

So I want to try my luck here. Is anyone else experiencing this or could give some advice?

Comment: Please check if this is your case:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207339
(the most recent comments)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user10550971 comment, I found the issue. The link to check if SOAP is enabled or not mentioned, that the PHP Soap extension was missing.
Although I would have sworn, that I didn't make any changes at server side, I did.
I updated my PHP version and forgot to install SOAP.